# SharePoint Online - Creating a custom PDF report by merging doc library contents on button click

Tags: pdf, online, m365

I am seeking some guidance on the best way to accomplish my client's request.

Ultimately we are on M365 - SharePoint Online and we have a sharepoint site that will contain 20-50 libraries at a time.

Each library will consist of 3 subfolders each housing different types of documents.

My client wants a button per library that when clicked, will convert and merge the contents of each subfolder into a single pdf report.

What is the best way to go about this?
SharePoint Extensions seem like the best course of action but that seems entirely client side. Is there something I am missing?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is probably to create an Azure function app, which can be called to complete the action. This is primarily because the processing involved in creating the PDF is probably too much for client side. This function app or Azure application would provide an API that can be used to request the creation of the PDF.

You could create the button either by creating an SPFx ListView Command Set which calls an API (you would need to secure this in some way) or a button that triggers a Power Automate flow which calls your API.

Comment: That is exactly how we decided to go. Thank you for confirming!